# Issue plotting several seaborn heatmap on the same matplotlib figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I've run into a small issue using matplotlib and seaborn's heatmap, and I cannot figure out what the issue is.

I want to display my data on a heatmap, as well as the sum of each row's value; however I cannot add it to the right of my initial data because their values are much higher/lower than the rest of my data, and make the heatmap unreadable.

To do so, I wanted to plot a second heatmap to the right of the first one, displaying only the sum of each rows.

I did the following:

```
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax1=sns.heatmap(np.transpose(res)[::-1], cmap="RdBu_r",center=0,annot=True,fmt=".1f",xticklabels=week_arr,yticklabels=tol_arr[::-1])
ax1.set_xlabel("Week")
ax1.set_ylabel("Tolerance")

ax2 = sns.heatmap(np.transpose([np.sum(res,axis=0)]),cmap="RdBu_r",center=0)

plt.show()
```

But I only get one heatmap on the second axe, and the first one is empty of any data.

Would anyone know why the first heatmap doesn't appear on the left subplot?

Thank you very much

**PS:** Test data

```
res=
[[-260.19999999999982,
  -383.40000000001874,
  -171.50000000001037,
  -157.10000000000693,
  -223.90000000001069],
 [-333.29999999999035,
  -288.10000000002884,
  -387.90000000000896,
  -287.6000000000015,
  -267.29999999999865],
 [-162.39999999999506,
  -135.50000000002248,
  -95.299999999992977,
  31.700000000002859,
  118.90000000000114],
 [-464.39999999999111,
  -386.20000000002841,
  -305.20000000003597,
  -162.40000000004926,
  -225.00000000001705],
 [-427.69999999996594,
  -424.39999999998417,
  -282.80000000000302,
  -336.90000000000407,
  -388.89999999999424]]
```

Comment: As `week_arr` and `tol_arr` are not included in your example data, and assuming they're not key components to the problem at hand, it might be best to leave the tick labels arguments out of the plotting commands.  Or just provide examples of those arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the axes objects you created with `plt.subplots()` to `sns.heatmap()` with the `ax` argument.  That's how Seaborn knows which axis to use for each plot.

```
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

sns.heatmap(np.transpose(res)[::-1], cmap="RdBu_r", ax=ax1) # <-- axis arg
ax1.set_xlabel("Week")
ax1.set_ylabel("Tolerance")

sns.heatmap(np.transpose([np.sum(res,axis=0)]),cmap="RdBu_r", ax=ax2)
```

[image: heatmap]

The way you currently have it set up, you're reassigning `ax1`  as the *output* from `heatmap()`, which doesn't actually make the link between the `ax1` plotting surface and the heatmap you want to draw on it.